# How far of mark is asking "open source alternatives to system.xml and system.xml.linq"?

Tags: discussion

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508885/open-source-alternatives-to-system-xml-and-system-xml-linq/9509111#9509111

was closed as not constructive, I have no problem with that but just want to understand the criteria that deemed it close worthy,

real reason : in future I apply the same criteria before posting similar questions

Comment: Oh, wait a minute... you were asking for OSS frameworks for XML processing?  Was that your question?  Because your original one doesn't make much sense at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for closure reads:

> ### closed as not constructive [...]
>
> This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

Basically, there is more than one valid answer to any question of the type *What are the alternatives to___*.

All might be equally good, but mostly it will be a matter of personal taste. Questions that have one definite answer are preferred.

Comment: "Basically, there is more than one valid answer to any question of the type What are the alternatives to___." agreed, I should have asked for a list of alternatives I guess.

Comment: @Arjang: See here: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: @RobertHarvey : That is so true, that helps a lot. Thank you